# TypeError: Cannot read property 'local' of undefined at Object.schedule (ng-cordova.js:5042)

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I have a problem scheduling local notifications with the ionic framework.

this is the angular module of my **app.js**

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic','chart.js','ngCordova'])
```

with a controller

```
.controller("ExampleController", function($scope, $ionicPlatform,$interval,$cordovaLocalNotification)
```

i try to create a notification with this method

```
scheduleInstantNotification = function () {
            $cordovaLocalNotification.schedule({
                id: 1,
                text: 'Value out of bound',
                title: 'Anomaly'
            }).then(function () {
                alert("Instant Notification set");
            });;
        };
```

when running on an android device i get this error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'local' of undefined
    at Object.schedule (ng-cordova.js:5042)
    at scheduleInstantNotification (app.js:138)
    at app.js:64
    at ionic.bundle.js:56230
    at Object.ready (ionic.bundle.js:2140)
    at Object.ready (ionic.bundle.js:56223)
    at app.js:62
    at callback (ionic.bundle.js:25611)
    at Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:30395)
    at Scope.$digest (ionic.bundle.js:30211)
```

I suspect that this error comes from the ngCordova library the error comes from this code part of the library

> ```
>   schedule: function (options, scope) {
>     var q = $q.defer();
>     scope = scope || null;
>     $window.cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule(options, function (result) {
>       q.resolve(result);
>     }, scope);
>     return q.promise;
>   },
> ```

the **$window.cordova.plugins.notification.local** object is undefined.

Did I miss something in the controller?

**EDIT**
adding the required plugin with:
    cordova plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications.git

causes a compiler error when running

```
ionic build android

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find any matches for com.android.support:support-v4:+ as     no versions of com.android.support:support-v4 are available.
     Searched in the following locations:

     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml
     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/
 Required by:
     :android:unspecified
```

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: I have edited my answer hope it helps !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the plugin with :

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications.git
```

as instructed on ngcordova documentation :

http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/localNotification/

Be sure also to call any method from the plugin after `$ionicPlatform.ready`.

**EDIT**
To your error when compiling with this plugin, please be sure to have Android Support Library installed with the Android SDK Manager.

Comment: adding the plugin causes an exception while building (see edit)